# break-word leaves the empty area in the div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have following html and css

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="a" style="
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: calc(65% - 75px);
    width: 21%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px 5px;
">
<span class="message" style="
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    word-break: break-word;
">let's check this one now for asd4ffdsa sassfhkloitrf.</span>
</div>

</body></html>
```

and it outputs the following layout
[image]

But the issue is that I am unable to get rid of the empty space as shown here 
[image]

I have tried every possible fix with positions, width auto, display properties but I am unable to get rid of the extra space here.

Comment: Give some width to `message` class and remove `width: auto;`

Comment: it does the same thing http://prntscr.com/lfv4lu @MerajKhan

Comment: use `text-align` property.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and to remove the empty space you should remove your **width** property or set it to auto since it forces **21%** of the page as its width.
So it should be like this:

```
<html><body>
    <div class="a" style="
      background-color: black;
      color: #fff;
      max-width: calc(65% - 75px);
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      padding: 3px 5px; ">
    <span class="message" style="
      width: auto;
      position: relative;
      text-align: right;
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      word-break: break-word; ">let's check this one now for asd4ffdsa sassfhkloitrf.</span> </div>

</body></html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

instead of break-word

Comment: why would I break the words?

Comment: because that spot is reserved for that long word and your text-align is right, you may either text-align: justify or break the word